# PHP loguearse con Mi Argentina

Tags: php, oauth2

ante que nada soy un programador básico de PHP y MySQL.

Me solicitaron que aplique esta autentificación en un sistema creado por mi y realmente no entiendo que debo hacer cuando llego al segundo paso.

La autentificación es de “Mi Argentina” que la explicación breve se encuentra en esta url https://argob.github.io/mi-argentina/doc/plataformas.html
Seguramente para mas de uno de ustedes esto es muy sencillo, pero a mi se me hizo lió cuando llego a la parte.

“Luego del primer paso, se recibe un parámetro code que hay que intercambiarlo por un token de acceso mediante un extremo. La llamada debe ser de servidor a servidor, ya que involucra la clave secreta de la aplicación (la clave secreta de la aplicación no debe aparecer nunca en el código del cliente).”

Yo logro que se logue y me envie el “code” y ahora no se que debo hacer para conseguir los datos del usuario que se logueo.

Por mis básicos conocimiento, tampoco se que significa de servidor a servidor, un código php que no muestre nada en pantalla o hay que instalar algo al servidor?

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Saludos!

Comment: Lo de servidor a servidor, se refiere a que tu php debe usar un cliente http, por ejemplo curl (googlea PHP CURL) para conectarse a otro servidor y hacer algo antes de devolver un resultado al usuario.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me pongo a leer sobre php y cURL.

Necesitaba una guia.

Saludos!